# Converting CSV file to JSON and send it to a JMS queue

Tags: json, csv, apache-camel

My aim is to read a CSV file, convert it to JSON, and send the generated JSON one by one to a JMS queue. My Code below:

```java
final BindyCsvDataFormat bindy=new BindyCsvDataFormat(camelproject.EquityFeeds.class);
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
CamelContext _ctx = new DefaultCamelContext(); 
_ctx.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
_ctx.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=data-sample.csv")
        .unmarshal(bindy)
        .marshal()
        .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson).log("${body}")
        .to("file:src/main/resources/?fileName=emp.json");
    }
    
});
```

**EquityFeeds** is my POJO class in the above code.

Issues:

1. No Output is produced. "emp.json" file does not get generated at the given location.
2. Also how do I split the generated JSON into individual JSON's and send it to a JMS queue like what I did for XML as below:

```java
.split(body().tokenizeXML("equityFeeds", null)).streaming().to("jms:queue:xml.upstream.queue");
```

**EquityFeeds (POJO):**

```java
@CsvRecord(separator = ",",skipFirstLine = true)
public class EquityFeeds {
        
    @DataField(pos = 1) 
    private String externalTransactionId;

    @DataField(pos = 2)
    private String clientId;

    @DataField(pos = 3)
    private String securityId;

    @DataField(pos = 4)
    private String transactionType;

    @DataField(pos = 5)
    private Date transactionDate;

    @DataField(pos = 6)
    private float marketValue; 

    @DataField(pos = 7)
    private String priorityFlag;
    
    // getters and setters... 
}
```

**Please Note:** I commented the `.marshal()` and `.json()` to check if the `.unmarshal()` is working but the unmarshal is also not working as "emp.json" is not getting created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing happens at all when starting the route then it is most likely due to the relative path you passed to the file component. Probably the execution directory of your Java process is not where you think it is and the file is not found. To simplify things I suggest you start with an absolute path. Once everything else is working figure out the correct relative path (your base should be the value of the `user.dir` system property).

Re your question about splitting the contents: This is answered in the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/dataformats/bindy-dataformat.html).

This works for me (Camel 3.1):

```
public class CsvRouteBuilder extends EndpointRouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(BindyModel.class);

        from(file("/tmp?fileName=simpsons.csv"))
            .unmarshal(bindy)
            .split(body())
            .log("Unmarshalled model: ${body}")
            .marshal().json()
            .log("Marshalled to JSON: ${body}")
            // Unique file name for the JSON output
            .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, () -> UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".json")
            .to(file("/tmp"));
    }
}

// Use lombok to generate all the boilerplate stuff
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
// Bindy record definition
@CsvRecord(separator = ";", skipFirstLine = true, crlf = "UNIX")
public static class BindyModel {

    @DataField(pos = 1)
    private String firstName;
    @DataField(pos = 2)
    private String middleName;
    @DataField(pos = 3)
    private String lastName;

}
```

Given this input in `/tmp/simpsons.csv`

```
firstname;middlename;lastname
Homer;Jay;Simpson
Marge;Jacqueline;Simpson
```

the log output looks like this

```
Unmarshalled model: RestRouteBuilder.BindyModel(firstName=Homer, middleName=Jay, lastName=Simpson)
Marshalled to JSON: {"firstName":"Homer","middleName":"Jay","lastName":"Simpson"}
Unmarshalled model: RestRouteBuilder.BindyModel(firstName=Marge, middleName=Jacqueline, lastName=Simpson)
Marshalled to JSON: {"firstName":"Marge","middleName":"Jacqueline","lastName":"Simpson"}
```

and two json files are written in `/tmp`.

Comment: thanks it worked. My "emp.json" file got created and it had all the JSON's as a list. 2 pressing issues have cropped up. 1) The date is coming as integer in my JSON like this: **"transactionDate":1385145000000**. The date field in my POJO class is `@DataField(pos = 5, pattern = "dd/MM/yy") private Date transactionDate;`    2) I am splitting the JSON as `.split().tokenize("},")`  and hence when I receive the JSON the **}** is missing for each individual JSON. How to resolve these issues. Please help.

Comment: Upvoting and/or accepting the answer if it is helpful is appreciated. Doing the split as I do in my above example will solve the JSON list problem. The date formatting you could control with Jackson annotations on your model class.

Comment: split issue is resolved. thanks a lot for that. My date issue still remains. I have added the annotations `@DataField(pos = 5, pattern = "dd/MM/yy") private Date transactionDate;` for date but the issue still persists. It's still unresolved.

Comment: `@DataField` is a Bindy annotation. For marshalling with Jackson you need to add a `@JsonFormat` annotation with the date pattern you want to use when unmarshalling to JSON.

Comment: If I use @JsonFormat only for the date field `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yy") private Date transactionDate;` and **@DataField** for other fields then the program is not working. Don't we have some solution for date field in Bindy annotation itself?

Comment: You need to use both annotations. One won't do the job of the other. Yes, there are other solutions. E.g.configuring  a custom Jackson object mapper instance for the marshalling step. Just fire up your favorite search engine and go for it.

Comment: When I am using both the annotations as mentioned in my post above then the code is not working i.e. not giving any output. How do I make it work?

Comment: Debug the route and see where your payload gets lost. The annotation won't be the problem.